# Firebug 1.11.1 on Firefox 19 Console Doesnt Work

Tags: firefox, console, firebug

Windows 7 up to date and fairly new.

This was working for weeks then just stopped working 5 days ago ~ 2/16/2013.

I have loaded and reloaded both of these programs. I have loaded old versions after clearing registry. Still no luck.

If anyone has any ideas--could be 3rd program interfering, but I have very little loaded on this computer.

Any help would be appreciated. I use this for development everyday. Any Idea of other combinations that let me edit the "c-s-s" in line would welcomed.

Comment: If you move the cursor to the bottom of the Firefox window when Firebug is active, do you get a vertical resize cursor so that you can expand it up?

Comment: Not sure about win 7 but in Firefox `Tools > Web Developer > Firebug > Options > Reset all Firebug options` might be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Recently firefox browser on my desktop was upgraded to 19.0 and fire bug to 1.11.2 . Am having trouble applying breakpoints and debugging scripts during run time. It was not the case a week before with older version.

Tried not to add it as "answer" but could not figure out an option add just detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is an problem with this version, i tried same and didn't work for me.
Now i am using Firebug 1.11.4 which is working just perfect for me with marklogic console for firebug 1.1.11.
hope it will help.

Thanks,
AKD